# Apply style to element with empty next sibling using Sass

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Is it possible to style an element based on whether or not its next sibling is empty.

```html
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="label">Hide me when submenu is empty</li>
        <ul class="submenu"></ul>
    </ul>
```

Let's assume that I want to hide `<LI class="label">` when `<UL class="submenu">` is empty.  Is this possible with CSS/Sass?

I've tried several variations of the example below, but haven't had any luck.

```css
    ul {
        > li {
            ~ ul:empty {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd prefer to stick with a CSS solution if possible.

Comment: [only-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) selector, maybe? Ideally, the `ul` wouldn't be output at all if there were no child-elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first, ***major*** problem your markup has is that it's invalid.

The only valid children of `<ul>` elements are `<li>`s. Therefore, in order to be valid, your inner `<ul>` has to be *inside the **`<li>`***. It can't be an immediate child of another `<ul>`.

But, even assuming a valid markup:

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="label">Hide me when submenu is empty
    <ul class="submenu"></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

... what you're trying to do is not possible using CSS alone, because the CSS parser never goes backwards (or upwards, for that matter).

If you can't do it with CSS alone you can't do it with SCSS alone, because SCSS is CSS syntactic sugar.

---

Here's how a JavaScript solution would look like:

```js
const uls = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
[...uls].forEach((ul) => {
  const emptyChildUls = ul.querySelectorAll('ul:empty');
  [...emptyChildUls].forEach((emptyUl) => {
    emptyUl.parentElement.classList.add('hasEmptyList');
  })
});
```

```css
ul li.hasEmptyList {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hide me when submenu is empty
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Obviously, you can change the applied classname to whatever you want. I chose to add a class rather than perform direct changes to the DOM elements so that you could still retain a level of control via CSS.

The above script has to run **after** you finished adding `<ul>`s to your page. If you add them after you ran the script, they won't have the class applied (you need to run the script again so they do).